# Рисование на bitmap большого размера

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, рисование

Допустим есть файл с большим изображением (2000 × 2000 пикселей или даже больше) - декодировать его целиком в bitmap чтобы вставить в canvas для использования различных draw-методов нельзя - это может вызвать out of memory.
Вопрос: как рисовать на таком большом изображении?

Comment: разбить его на тайлы, как это сделано во всех картографических движках, только там изображения чуть больше чем 2000 пикселей

Comment: как я понимаю тайлы это просто небольшие отдельные битмапы , скопированные с разных участков большого битмапа - если рисовать на них , то и результат будет сохранятся на них , а не на большом битмапе - а нужно чтобы изменения вносились именно в "общий" - большой битмап , чтобы потом его с этими изменениями можно было сохранить в файл

Comment: Можно перед считыванием сжать картинку, нарисовать на ней и потом вернуть исходное состояние. Но качество чуток потеряется.

Comment: если вернуть исходный размер прямо в коде (например с помощью createScaledBitmap) , то это приведёт к созданию большого битмапа и переполнению памяти , кроме того при повторной перерисовке каждый цикл "сжатия-растягивания" битмапа будет приводить к всё большей потере качества изображения